# Chassan and Kallah

Tags: drush, wedding

Why in Hebrew is the word Chosson mean both Groom and son in law and Kallah means bride and daughter in law?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rav Chaim Kanievsky answers this is the lesson that the relationship that the bride and groom and father in law and mother in laws relationship should always be like they are always the Chassan and Kallah.

Comment: Sheva Brachos torah is always useful